# invalid operands to binary expression ('int_node' and const 'int_node')

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner, many questions around me. I have defined `!=` operator of `int_node`, but when I compile this code, show error:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('int_node' and const 'int_node')

The IDE that I use is xcode 4.6.

Below is my all code

```
typedef struct int_node{
    int val;
    struct int_node *next;
} int_t;

template <typename Node>
struct node_wrap{
    Node *ptr;

    node_wrap(Node *p = 0) : ptr(p){}
    Node &operator *() const {return *ptr;}
    Node *operator->() const {return ptr;}

    node_wrap &operator++() {ptr = ptr->next; return *this;}
    node_wrap operator++(int) {node_wrap tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp;}

    bool operator == (const node_wrap &i) const {return ptr == i.ptr;}
    bool operator != (const node_wrap &i) const {return ptr != i.ptr;}
} ;

template <typename Iterator, typename T>
Iterator find(Iterator first, Iterator last,  const T& value)
{
    while (first != last && *first != value) // invalid operands to binary experssion ('int_node' and const 'int_node')
    {
        ++first;
        return first;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct int_node *list_head = nullptr;
    struct int_node *list_foot = nullptr;
    struct int_node valf;
    valf.val = 0;
    valf.next = nullptr;
    find(node_wrap<int_node>(list_head), node_wrap<int_node>(list_foot), valf);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: A) Indent your code, please B) You *say* you defined `operator !=` for int_node but I only see it for node_wrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My compiler says

> "1>main.cpp(28): error C2676:
>    binary '!=' :
>   **'int_node' does not define this operator** or a conversion to a type
>   acceptable to the predefined operator"

which is true.

We could define `!=` in terms of `==` e.g. for your missing `int_node`

```
bool operator == (const int_node &i) const {return val == i.val;}
bool operator != (const int_node &i) const {return !(*this==i);}
```

You need to define the operators - should they check the node as well?

BTW, do you intend to return `first` no matter what?

```
while (first != last && *first != value)
{
    ++first;
    return first;
    //     ^^^^^
    //     |||||
}
```

Comment: than you ,i add the code that you give to my project, succesed. i have know the error under your help. very than you. i'm chinese ，my english is very garbage

Comment: @BestWater Good luck. Give me a tick if it helped.

Comment: sorry, i also want do as you say,but my english is very pool and use this web for the first time. so i don't know how i give you a tick.please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things in there:

- `struct int_node` does not define any comparison operator between itself and a `const int_node &` instance, and that responds to your question;
- in the function `Iterator find(Iterator first, Iterator last,  const T& value)` there is a `return` statement within the `while` statement, so the `while` is useless, or the `return` should be put outside it.

Comment: thank you, yes,i don't define operator != for int_node. i'm a beginer, so i don't special know operator overloading when i ask this question.

Comment: the fact is that in this case is essential. The compiler dos know nothing about how to take care of a comparison between an `int_node` and a `const int_node`, simply defining something like `bool operator !=(const int_node & i) { return val != i.val; }` is the solution to that: it takes another `int_node` reference, which is `const` because you don't need to modify it, and a boolean is returned (I supposed the real comparison were between the two `int_node::val`).